# How to execute a command for each loop in awk?

Tags: awk, binary-data

I'm using awk to split a binary stream and I can get each part into a for loop like this.

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)`

I don't want to convert each field to text or arguments, but simply pass it directly to a command.

I'm trying to find something like this,

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) system("decode")`

but this obviously doesn't work. decode receives no input.

How do I get decode to receive each field in the loop?

Comment: Why are you using awk to call a shell tool instead of just doing this in shell? I suspect the answer is "because I'm doing more than this" and then whatever extra you are doing will drive the decision on the correct answer. So, post a complete script with sample input and expected output (i.e. a [mcve]) so we can try to help you.

Comment: There's not much than what I've posted here frankly. I'm using awk because this is the only way I could manage to use multi-character delimiters. Also, most shell tools strip whitespace etc. making them a nightmare to work with binary

Comment: What about avoiding awk and using pure shell? `xargs -n1 decode < input_file.txt` might do what you're looking for.  Change `$IFS` if you don't want to split on white space.

Comment: @akula1001 shell tools do not strip whitespace. If that's happening to you then you're probably just forgetting to quote variables or not setting `IFS=` on a read or making some other mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't this works for you?

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i | "decode"
close("decode")
```

It sends each field (or byte in your case) to a pipe connected to the "decode" program.

After that, close the "decode" pipe to force a flush of all the data on that pipe.

You can read more about gawk redirection on https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html

If you want to execute "decode" for each single byte, just close the pipe in each iteration:

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    print $i | "decode"
    close("decode")
}
```

Comment: This calls decode just once with the entire stream of data. What I need is to call decode with each $i

Comment: I don't know what you really want to achieve here. If your file has 1Mbyte you'll be executing decode 1 million times. That makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a little? For me, a few thousand calls is what I estimate.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the code you're asking for. Execute decode for each binary byte. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! the close did the trick. it needs the exact same string as the original command.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```sh
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) system("decode "$i)}' input_file.txt
```

This should pass each field, contained in awk variable `$i`, to the `decode` external program. Mind the variable is outside the quotes for `"decode "`, or it would be interpreted by the shell instead of awk.

Comment: Close, but this still goes through the shell. I get an error like [sh: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"']. What I'd like is to pass data over stdin to decode, because the data is binary.

Comment: I see. Actually @valrog understood much better than I did. His|Her command seems to work for me, and to call the program for each field. Did you try enclosing the `print` and `decode` into a same set of curly braces? This is what I used: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i | "decode"; close("decode")}}' input_file`